# Sending out html formatted email with attachments from workspace in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to use Jenkins to

1) run a bash script to select data from a database

2) load it into a csv and store it in the workspace

3) Use the appropriate email extension to send a HTML formatted email with the file contents from the workspace attached.

What would be the best way to go about achieving step 3?

Comment: have you considered https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

It supports HTML formatted emails and attachments from workspace:

[image]

Comment: To send out "pretty" HTML, you will want to make the Default Content to use a template.  I use `${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}`.

Comment: I had a problem with sending Jenkins emails through sendgrid's smtp service with turned the mails into HTML in a way that lost the newlines int he plain text. Using `${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}` as my Default Content and making HTML the default content type solved that problem.